# Hours needed for international/domestic transfer in Soekarno–Hatta International Airport

Tags: transit, airports, jakarta, cgk

I am arriving in Jakarta on the 21st of July at 15:40. The plan is to fly directly to Yogyakarta, where we plan on doing a couple of tours. I am fully aware that it is the holidays down there and everyone is travelling and everything is crowded (the reason why I want to order as much as possible already). Not much I can do about that. It happens to be the time when I also have vacations.

How long time do I need to count on from landing in Soekarno–Hatta to the departure of my plane to Yogyakarta. So I don't miss the plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Depends!**  Immigration and Customs at Jakarta can be *very* slow (an hour in line is not uncommon), so I would recommend adding a generous amount of buffer.  I would not risk an int'l-dom connection on separate tickets with less than **three hours** to spare.

- **Terminal 2** is used by all international airlines (except Air Asia), and by Garuda domestic flights (only).  The published minimum connecting time for Garuda int'l to domestic is **60 minutes**, but this assumes you have a connecting ticket and are already checked-in; add *at least* 30 minutes if you need to check in again.
- **Terminal 3** is used by Air Asia int'l and domestic flights.  They operate only a very limited "Fly-Thru" connecting service, and [Yogya is not on the list](http://www.airasia.com/id/en/latest-news/fly-thru-via-jakarta.page). Regular check-in closes 45 minutes before departure, so I would allow *at least* 2 hours for the connection.
- All other domestic flights use either Terminal 1 or Terminal 3, so you will need to transfer with a shuttle bus (every 10 minutes, in theory), which easily adds half an hour to your transit time.